# Wordpress admin notice in plugin function

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, hooks, actions, notices

i have sample wordpress plugin class. Im hooking woocommerce `woocommerce_saved_order_items` and i want create a admin notice. Add action from __construct works, but when i want create a notice in hook function it doesnt appears, where is the problem?

```
 class SomeClass {

        private static $instance;


        public function __construct() {
            add_action('woocommerce_saved_order_items',array($this,'orderStatusChange'),10,1);
            add_action('admin_notices', array($this,'simple_notice')); // This works
        }

        public static function getInstance() {
            if(!self::$instance)
                self::$instance = new SomeClass();

            return self::$instance;
        }


        public function orderStatusChange($orderID){
            add_action('admin_notices', 'simple_notice');//This not works
        }



        function simple_notice(){
            ?>
            <div class="updated notice is-dismissible">
                <p>Thank you for using this plugin! <strong>You are awesome</strong>.</p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

    }


    SomeClass::getInstance();
```

Comment: Are you found any solution about this? I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is pretty simple. Your callback for this hook is not a simple function but some method of a class.

If you add action like this:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'simple_notice');
```

you tell WP that there is some simple function called `simple_notice` and it should be called when hook `admin_notices` is processed. But... There is no such function anywhere in your code.

The function you want to call is method in your class, so you have to pass not only the name of function, but also object of given class, so WP is able to call this method. (And you've done it correctly in __construct).

This line works

```
add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'simple_notice')); // This works
```

because the method is passed with full details - as an array describing object and it's method to call.

Comment: This is not working for me.

Comment: @Radmation This is answer to the question “why my code doesn’t work”, not general tutorial “how to create notices”. So yeah - most probably it won’t work in your case, unless you have the same code as OP.

Comment: Well my code is built similar. I figured out a solution for my case however :D. What I was doing was posting data the non-ajax way and in my post handler I was wanting to set admin notices up. I ended up using the wp_options table to persist the "notice" between redirects..